# Need to implement a Elastic search query with both $select and $filter

Tags: java, elasticsearch, odata, filtering

I have a Odata Query : 
**/ecommerceadmin/ODataService.svc/search?$select=status&$filter=id eq 'test.com'and name eq 'abc'**

How can I implement the code in elastic search to get the data accordingly.What method in **SearchSourceBuilder** should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably easily get away with one `match` and one `term` query like this:

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;

BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "abc"))       // 1.
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("id", "test.com"));  // 2.

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("ecommerce_index")
        .setTypes("ecommerce_type")
        .setQuery(query)
        .setFetchSource(new String[]{"status"}, null)    // 3.
        .setFrom(0)
        .setSize(10)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

In the above code:

1. takes care of the `name eq 'abc'` $filter
2. takes care of the `id eq 'test.com'` $filter
3. takes care of the `$select=status` part