# Convert OData filter query to Elasticsearch query in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, .net-core, odata

I would like to convert an OData query:

`$filter=(ContentProvider%20eq%20'HBO'%20or%20ContentProvider%20eq%20'ParamountPlus')%20and%20ProgramType%20eq%20'Series'`

... to an Elasticsearch Query DSL, or NEST object in .NET.

How anyone done something similar, or have any tips?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38085596/4604579

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this for Java?

Comment: That answers the first part of the question, i.e. from OData to ES-DSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, feel free to contribute with issues, feature ideas, example OData queries that you would like to be supported:
https://github.com/cristipufu/elasticsearch-odata-net